# Can I get back Snow-Leopard-like application hiding (Cmd-H) in Lion?

Tags: macos

Till Mac OS X Snow Leopard, pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while using an application did two things...

1. The application hid itself from view.
2. The application placed itself at the end of the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> switcher.

The 2nd point was *very* useful, because when I hid an app, I knew I wasn't going to use it for some time. Sending it to the end of the switcher helped me focus on the apps I was using more.

However, in Lion, even though <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> hides the app, it only moves it to the next position in the switcher. This is equivalent to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>ing between 2 apps, except that the app is now also hidden from view. IMO, this breaks a **fundamental** feature of the switcher and the app-hiding concept. I have no idea why this was done.

Does anyone have clues on how, if at all, this could be fixed? Or maybe places I should start looking? I just hope there's a preference buried in some plist file somewhere...

Comment: I never noticed the position yet...;) Nice question... ;)

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Lion to me. Perhaps let Apple know via feedback@apple.com

Comment: I just entered a report/request for this at http://www.apple.com/feedback/.

Comment: I've been aggravated by this as well, and have also filed feedback.  I don't know of any solutions, though, except for moving to a different cmd-tab switcher like Witch.

Comment: @khedron: How does Witch fix this? It shows same order as Cmd-Tab. If I'm missing something, I'd love to know, because this mis-feature is driving me up the wall.

Comment: The thing that bugs me the most is that when hiding an application, the system will automatically switch to the most recent application---even if it is in another Space. For example, I always have Chrome in full-screen mode, but Mail and my text-editor are on the normal desktop Space (not in full-screen). I'm in Chrome, then switch to Mail for a second to check it. When I'm done checking mail, I hit `Command-H`. I expect the mail window to hide and see the text-editor behind it. But no, the OS switches to Chrome, automatically swooshing to the next Space. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great question. This might be intended behavior rather than a bug. Mission Control seems to have blended both the old Expose and the old Spaces. With that in mind, launching a new app Full Screen places it on its own desktop. When you get to Mission Control you see it placed to the right of the original, empty Desktop. Open a second app Full Screen and that will place it again on its own desktop, next to the first Full Screen app you opened.

Just like the Home Screens in iOS and the old Spaces, it would seem that Apple intends these desktops to stay, space-wise, in the same place. Mail is "to the left" of Safari if I opened Safari after opening Mail. I agree that this spatial notion collides with our pre-conceived understanding of the switcher. That is same reason why hiding is disabled for Full Screen apps (pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will *not* hide a Full Screen app).

If everything is full screen, the concept of hiding becomes less relevant. I think back to the older versions of Mac OS, where you had stacks upon stacks of windows. Hiding an app like Adobe Photoshop (and all of its many opened child windows for each one of my many opened images) made sense. If such window "stacking" is spatially not there (because those Full Screen apps are now side-by-side, they're not really stacked) then it almost makes sense that it doesn't work.

Having said all of that, I could not agree more that Lion has completely messed around with the workflow of many old-time Mac users. I do not necessarily agree with Apple's decisions here, I am just trying to play advocate and see if this one in particular has some explanation that makes sense. Hope this helps.

**Update:** 
This [article](http://tidbits.com/e/12398) at TidBITS mentions a new feature in Lion called Automatic Termination. I was not aware of this feature. I wonder if the behavior that is being experienced by this question's author is related to this.

Comment: I don't see how full screen mode relates to the behaviour of ⌘H when dealing with *non-full-screen* apps.

Comment: I noticed that Cmd+H does not work for full-screen apps, so I thought he was asking referring to full-screen apps only. However, after reading the question again, it seems that he is not specifying one way or the other. If he is talking about NON full-screen apps whose Hide command does not work, I would agree that it is most likely a bug. The point of my answer above, however, was that if he was indeed talking about full-screen apps; than it could be one of those UI decisions by Apple--and I speculated that they could be seeing full-screen app switching as an analogy to the iOS app switcher.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to a TidBITS article about a feature in Lion called Automatic Termination. It sounds like an app can be terminated by Lion and removed from the Command+Tab switcher.

Comment: I don't think the Cmd+H window stack behaviour is related to automatic termination either, for at least two reasons: The application I'm hiding still has open windows that I didn't close; the app in question is *not* being automatically terminated by the OS, it's still running.

Comment: @Christian\ Correa — You, sir, know your stuff. Have you considered pursuing Apple certification such as ACSP or ACTC?

Comment: I too don't think this answer, while being surely interesting, has anything to do with the original question. Apple changed Cmd-H behaviour and it's a lot less useful now as many of us noticed and the original poster nicely described. In short -- if an app can be hidden it should be moved to the end of the Cmd-Tab apps list, otherwise it's simply pointless and irritating behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As this has been bugging me ever since this was changed I've given it another go. It seems the only working way so far is to imitate it by switching to all open apps before hiding. 
Not sure if applescript changed a bit but I had to change willlma's script like this for it to work. This also has substantially less key presses so should do the job faster.

```
delay 0.5
set i to 0
tell application "System Events"
    set first_app to name of the first process whose frontmost is true
    repeat with p in every process
        if visible of p then
            set i to i + 1
        end if
    end repeat
    repeat i - 1 times
        key down command
        key down shift
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.01
        key up shift
        key up command
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    set visible of process first_app to false
end tell
```

It will show some flickering while switching and the delay can be too short if some animations take longer (like switching to full-screen apps), so the numbers are probably not optimal for all Macs or situations.
And while it should be possible to set an Automator Service with a global hotkey, nothing happened for me. I've had more luck with the little application [iCanHazShortcut](https://github.com/deseven/icanhazshortcut) where you can call `osascript <scriptname>` when pressing cmd-h.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get back Snow-Leopard-like application hiding (Cmd-H) in Lion? … The application placed itself at the end of the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> switcher. …

Since [Application Switcher was introduced](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA25752) in Mac OS 8.5, there have been various changes.

## In Lion

It's probably impossible to get the old placement with the newer Application Switcher.

If you identify the binary used for the switcher, a run of [`strings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/strings.1.html)(1) might reveal more.

> … This might be [intended behaviour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/19683/8546) …

I believe so.

> … [wasn't going to use it for some time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/19185/8546) …

The behaviour in Lion is probably for a significant proportion of use cases where hiding is **short term**.

With a comfortable key combination (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> is less ergonomic):

- Lion is quicker than Snow Leopard for showing a hidden app.

### Beyond Lion

In Mountain Lion, for example, there's another change: [no longer an endless cycle](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9754269#9754269) in response to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

In OS X 10.9 there may be further changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely the intended behaviour. It also doesn't fade the icon, which I find annoying. I wrote a GUI applescript that imitates the old way of doing things. Copy paste this into Applescript, save it, then use [fastscripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to associate it with a keyboard shortcut (like ctrl+H).

```
set i to 0
tell application "System Events"
    set first_app to name of the first process whose frontmost is true
    repeat with p in every process
        if p is visible then
            set i to i + 1
        end if
    end repeat
    repeat i - 1 times
        key down command
        repeat i - 1 times
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.03
        end repeat
        key up command
        delay 0.03
    end repeat
    set visible of process first_app to false
end tell
```

Comment: error "System Events got an error: Can’t get visible." number -1728 from visible

Comment: Thanks for the script. I'm not actually using it and didn't test it for the exact purposes you set out (was inspecting it for another similar thing), but am just noting for anyone, I had to put " " around visible in the fifth line so it's: `if p is "visible" then`.

Comment: As for fading the icon, that's easy to fix by [installing TinkerTool](https://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html).