# How can I make ⌘H send an app to the back of the ⌘Tab stack on Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get back Snow-Leopard-like application hiding (Cmd-H) in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19185/can-i-get-back-snow-leopard-like-application-hiding-cmd-h-in-lion)

I just upgraded from Tiger (on an old MacBook) to Lion on a new MacBook Air. I had become accustomed to using ⌘H to both hide an application *and* to put it to the back of the ⌘Tab order.

On Lion, the ⌘H command still hides the window but doesn't change the position of the application in the ⌘Tab order. Pressing ⌘H then ⌘Tab brings the application right back to the foreground. By hiding the app, I want to say that I'm not interested in using it for now.

Is there another keystroke that sends an application back to the bottom of the ⌘Tab stack? Or is there a way to change the behaviour of ⌘H to hide *and* send to the back of the stack?