# Snow Leopard hidden app behavior in Lion

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get back Snow-Leopard-like application hiding (Cmd-H) in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19185/can-i-get-back-snow-leopard-like-application-hiding-cmd-h-in-lion)

I have 10.7 running on my personal laptop and 10.6 on my work machine, and recently noticed they act differently on hidden apps.

In 10.6, when I hide an app then hold down <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it shows a list of all the open apps and the hidden app will be at the end of the app-switcher. This way, if I just press (instead of holding down) <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> after hiding the app, it will not switch back and show that hidden app immediately.

However, in 10.7, Apple changed things up entirely: that hidden app will stay in its position after I hide it, so if I hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I'll immediately unhide the app I just hid, which seems to defeat the point of hiding the app.

So I am wondering if there is a way I can get that 10.6 hidden app behavior back on 10.7?